# Swtich to New Exepreince

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, new-experience, classic-experience

I am using SharePoint online on office 365 and the library was set to the classic experience.

I went to library settings, advanced and then changed it to new experience.

Unfortunately, the library hasn't been switched to the new experience.

I am using internet explorer 11.

Comment: What is the default experience set for SharePoint site??

Comment: how can I check the expereince on the SharePoint site ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this issue only occurs on a certain library, In your browser's address bar, delete everything in the URL after `.aspx`. Then, add `?=contents=1` to the end of the URL and press Enter.

A list or document library hidden web part will be displayed as `XsltListViewWebPart`. Locate any web part that isn't for the list or document library. Select the web part, and then press Delete.

Browse back to the document library page, and then view the new experience.

If that does not work, Open developer tools(F12) in the browser. Just click F12 function key.

Click on application tab,expand cookies section and select the SharePoint online site which you currently working on.

Delete the one with the name ‘spinu’ that has the value.

Refresh the browser and that should work.

You can check detailed information here:

[SharePoint Online list or library doesn't use the new experience as expected](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sharepoint-online-list-or-library-doesn-t-use-the-new-experience-as-expected-153ea01f-2667-430d-acd0-01bed6205a28)

[Switch back to modern view in SharePoint online](https://infosharepoint.com/switch-back-to-modern-view-in-sharepoint-online/)

Comment: in my library there is nothting after .aspx . it looks something like this https://""""".sharepoint.com/sites/site""""/""""/TestLibrary/Forms/AllItems.aspx and I have used the webpart ScriptEditor to add a script and not sure if that could have any effect

Comment: @Ed1995 Hi, that is the reason why you cannot switch to modern experience. The classic web parts are not supported in modern pages. As you add the script editor, the page was transferred to classic experience.

Comment: are Metadata navigation available for the new expereince ? I created a new library with no webpart so the switching to the new expereince was successful. However I put the metadata navigation but its not showing